# I can't access to global variables

Tags: php, global-variables

I'm trying get access to variables - globals:

The next code work for me:

```
$a = 1;
$b = 2;
function Sum()
{
    $GLOBALS['b'] = $GLOBALS['a'] + $GLOBALS['b'] ;
}
Sum();
echo $b;
```

and this not work:

```
$a = 1;
$b = range(1, 500);
function Sum()
{
    $GLOBALS['b'] = $GLOBALS['a'] + $GLOBALS['b'] ;
}
Sum();
echo $b;
```

What's the problem?

note: I don't want to use: `global $a; global $b;`

Comment: How exactly are you supposed to be able to add a number and an array? If you want to add the number to each element of the array, use a for-loop.

Comment: This question, as it turns out, has nothing to do with global variables. But as a tip, avoid using global variables as much as possible - as your code grows, they will make it harder and harder to work with.

Comment: @Jose you've been making a number of very poor quality suggested edits, there's currently a [meta discussion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223423/is-it-possible-to-flag-edit-reviews-as-invalid) about it. Please take care when editing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you are trying to do SUM of `array` and number :
this is working :

```
<?php
$a = 1;
$b = range(1, 500);

function Sum()
{
    $GLOBALS['b'] = $GLOBALS['a'] + $GLOBALS['b'][0] ;//0 or any index
}
Sum();
echo $b;
?>
```

If you want to add **`$a`** to **sum of array `$b`**  then use `array_sum()` like this :

```
   function Sum()
    {
        $GLOBALS['b'] = $GLOBALS['a'] + array_sum($GLOBALS['b']) ; 
    }
```

Comment: Why do you apply an index to the result of `array_sum()`? It's not an array.

Comment: just because i copied the line  from the first code of my answer , i edited

Answer (score 1):

In your second example you are using php "range":
http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php

which will return an array then you are attempting an addition within your Sum function.

ERROR = Types do not match in the second function!